# How to add javascript to ASP.NET hyperlink control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, hyperlink

How can I enter this URL into a HyperLink ASP.NET Control ?

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url={URL}" 
   onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,'','menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;">
    <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-64.png" alt="Share on Google+"/>
</a>
```

Comment: Are you having problems with the {URL} bit?

Comment: no, I don't know how to include the javascript onclick

Comment: well thats not the URL... that is the onclick javascript

Comment: thanks for editing the title - was misleading ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `onclick`.  Any properties that are not recognized by ASP.Net are passed as-is.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="Server"
    NavigateUrl="https://plus.google.com/share?url={URL}"
    onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '',
      'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');
      return false;">
  ...
</asp:HyperLink>
```

In general, if you don't need server-side access to a control, I wouldn't recommend converting them to server-side because it adds extra unnecessary processing to the server.

Answer (score 1):

To add it in the declarative syntax just add it i.e.

```
<asp:HyperLink 
    runat="server" 
    ID="theLink" 
    onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '','menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');
  return false;">
</asp:HyperLink>
```

You must note that OnClick (which is event binding for ASP.NET and the lowercase version onclick are NOT the same)

If you want to do it in code behind then you can do it via the WebControl.Attributes array ;)